# Affine algebraic variety as a set of common zeroes of holomorphic functions on ${\mathbb C}^n$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $V$ be an affine algebraic variety in ${\mathbb C}^n$, i.e. a set of common zeroes of some set $S$ of polynomials on ${\mathbb C}^n$:
$$
V=\{z\in {\mathbb C}^n:\ \forall p\in S\quad p(z)=0\}.
$$
Let $I$ be the ideal in the algebra ${\mathcal P}({\mathbb C}^n)$ of polynomials on ${\mathbb C}^n$ consisting of all polynomials that vanish on $V$:
$$
I=\{f\in {\mathcal P}({\mathbb C}^n):\ \forall z\in V\quad f(z)=0\}.
$$
By [Hilbert's basis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem), $I$ is generated by a finite set $q_1,...,q_k$ of polynomials in ${\mathcal P}({\mathbb C}^n)$, so we can think that
$$
V=\{z\in {\mathbb C}^n:\ q_1(z)=...=q_k(z)=0\},
$$
and

> each polynomial $f\in {\mathcal P}({\mathbb C}^n)$ that vanishes on $V$, 
>   $$
> \forall z\in V\quad f(z)=0,
> $$
>   has the form
>   $$
> f(z)=f_1(z)\cdot q_1(z)+...+f_k(z)\cdot q_k(z)
> $$
>   for some $f_1,...,f_k\in {\mathcal P}({\mathbb C}^n)$.

A.Yu.Pirkovskii in his [work of 2008](http://www.ams.org/journals/mosc/2008-69-00/S0077-1554-08-00169-6/home.html) (Example 3.6, p.42) uses sheaves, the analitization functor and the [Cartan theorem B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_theorems_A_and_B) for proving a similar statement for holomorphic functions:

> each holomorphic function $f\in {\mathcal O}({\mathbb C}^n)$ that vanishes on $V$, 
>   $$
> \forall z\in V\quad f(z)=0,
> $$
>   can be approximated in ${\mathcal O}({\mathbb C}^n)$ by the functions of the form 
>   $$
> f_1(z)\cdot q_1(z)+...+f_k(z)\cdot q_k(z)
> $$
>   where $q_1,...,q_k$ are still the same polynomials in ${\mathcal P}({\mathbb C}^n)$ that generate $I$ (and they don't change), and $f_1,...,f_k$ are arbitrary holomorphic functions from ${\mathcal O}({\mathbb C}^n)$ (or polynomials from ${\mathcal P}({\mathbb C}^n)$, this is not important since ${\mathcal P}({\mathbb C}^n)$ is dense in ${\mathcal O}({\mathbb C}^n)$), and ${\mathcal O}({\mathbb C}^n)$ is endowed with the usual topology of uniform convergence on compact sets in ${\mathbb C}^n$.

I have a feeling that using analytization and the Cartan theorem, is extra in this situation, and one can prove this in a simpler way. Am I right? Can this have a more or less simple explanation?